# Pivot / Unpivot SQL Query

Tags: sql-server

Good day, I have a simple table from an direct input from my app , and here is the table  and record example

```
KodeDinasHeader  anggaran_makan anggaran_so anggaran_transport  anggaran_tiket  anggaran_kost   realisasi_makan realisasi_so    realisasi_transport realisasi_tiket realisasi_kost
DN0000001               3500         2000           5000             10000          7600            5000           1750                 4760             10000          9760
```

is it possible to have a result like this ?

```
         Anggaran   Realisasi
Makan       3500    5000
So          2000    1750
Tiket       10000   10000
Transport   5000    4760
Kost        7600    9760
```

I have read online about Pivot and Unpivot https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx. It seems i still need a guide. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to a UNPIVOT would be to use a `CROSS APPLY` then conditional aggregation to "pivot" the results of this.

e.g.

```
DECLARE @myTable TABLE (KodeDinasHeader NVARCHAR(255), anggaran_makan INT, anggaran_so INT, anggaran_transport INT, anggaran_tiket INT, anggaran_kost INT, realisasi_makan INT, realisasi_so INT, realisasi_transport INT, realisasi_tiket INT, realisasi_kost INT);
INSERT @myTable VALUES 
      ('DN0000001', 3500, 2000, 5000, 10000, 7600, 5000, 1750, 4760, 10000, 9760)
    , ('DN0000002', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);

SELECT KodeDinasHeader
     , Z
     , MAX(CASE WHEN Y = 'angarran' THEN X END) angarran
     , MAX(CASE WHEN Y = 'realisasi' THEN X END) realisasi
FROM @myTable
CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES (anggaran_makan, 'angarran', 'makan')
         , (anggaran_so, 'angarran', 'so')
         , (anggaran_transport, 'angarran', 'transport')
         , (anggaran_tiket, 'angarran', 'tiket')
         , (anggaran_kost, 'angarran', 'kost')
         , (realisasi_makan, 'realisasi', 'makan')
         , (realisasi_so, 'realisasi', 'so')
         , (realisasi_transport, 'realisasi', 'transport')
         , (realisasi_tiket, 'realisasi', 'tiket')
         , (realisasi_kost, 'realisasi', 'kost')) W(X, Y, Z)
GROUP BY Z, KodeDinasHeader;
```

I find this a lot easier to do than unpivoting, personally. The cross apply is basically getting the value for each column in the row, and from that you're repivoting it (with conditional aggregation) based on what the category is (which needs to be done manually in your case, since it's based on column names).

EDIT:

Here's a way you could do it with a standard PIVOT/UNPIVOT if you really wanted to (or just to understand the concept).

```
DECLARE @myTable TABLE (KodeDinasHeader NVARCHAR(255), anggaran_makan INT, anggaran_so INT, anggaran_transport INT, anggaran_tiket INT, anggaran_kost INT, realisasi_makan INT, realisasi_so INT, realisasi_transport INT, realisasi_tiket INT, realisasi_kost INT);
INSERT @myTable VALUES 
      ('DN0000001', 3500, 2000, 5000, 10000, 7600, 5000, 1750, 4760, 10000, 9760)
    , ('DN0000002', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);

SELECT KodeDinasHeader, colSecondHalf, anggaran, realisasi
FROM (
    SELECT KodeDinasHeader, val, LEFT(col, CHARINDEX('_', col) - 1) colFirstHalf, RIGHT(col, LEN(col) - CHARINDEX('_', col)) colSecondHalf
    FROM @myTable
    UNPIVOT (val for col in (anggaran_makan, anggaran_so, anggaran_transport, anggaran_tiket, anggaran_kost, realisasi_makan, realisasi_so, realisasi_transport, realisasi_tiket, realisasi_kost)) z) t
PIVOT (MAX(val) FOR colFirstHalf IN (anggaran, realisasi)) P;
```

Essentially, you're unpivoting each of the columns, then getting your row values by splitting the name of the column at the underscore, then pivoting based on the first half of the column name.